# .NET System Type to SqlDbType

Tags: c#, ado.net, system.data

I was looking for a smart conversion between .Net System.Type and SqlDbType. What I found it was the following idea:

```
private static SqlDbType TypeToSqlDbType(Type t)
{
    String name = t.Name;
    SqlDbType val = SqlDbType.VarChar; // default value
    try
    {
        if (name.Contains("16") || name.Contains("32") || name.Contains("64"))
            {
                name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 2);
            }
            val = (SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SqlDbType), name, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // add error handling to suit your taste
        }

        return val;
    }
```

The code above is not really nice and is a code smell, which is why I wrote the following, naïve, not smart, but useful function, based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx:

```
   public static SqlDbType ConvertiTipo(Type giveType)
    {
       var typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();

        typeMap[typeof(string)] = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        typeMap[typeof(char[])] = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        typeMap[typeof(int)] = SqlDbType.Int;
        typeMap[typeof(Int32)] = SqlDbType.Int;
        typeMap[typeof(Int16)] = SqlDbType.SmallInt;
        typeMap[typeof(Int64)] = SqlDbType.BigInt;
        typeMap[typeof(Byte[])] = SqlDbType.VarBinary;
        typeMap[typeof(Boolean)] = SqlDbType.Bit;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime)] = SqlDbType.DateTime2;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset)] = SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset;
        typeMap[typeof(Decimal)] = SqlDbType.Decimal;
        typeMap[typeof(Double)] = SqlDbType.Float;
        typeMap[typeof(Decimal)] = SqlDbType.Money;
        typeMap[typeof(Byte)] = SqlDbType.TinyInt;
        typeMap[typeof(TimeSpan)] = SqlDbType.Time;

        return typeMap[(giveType)];
     }
```

Does someone have idea of how to get the same result in a cleaner, better and nice way?

Comment: Making dictionary conversion is OK. Done *once* in a life time. :) (less there is a change)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your approach is a good start, but populating that dictionary should only be done **once**, as Ian says in a comment.

There is a GIST here that is based on the same idea, although it doesn't convert between the same sets of types: https://gist.github.com/abrahamjp/858392

**Caveat**

I have [a working example](http://atornblad.se/converting-from-type-to-sqldbtype) below, but you need to be aware that this approach does have a few problems. For example:

- For a `string`, how do you pick the correct one between `Char`, `NChar`, `VarChar`, `NVarChar`, `Text` or `NText` *(or even `Xml`, maybe)*?
- And for blobs like `byte[]`, should you use `Binary`, `VarBinary` or `Image`?
- For `decimal`, `float` and `double`, should you go for `Decimal`, `Float`, `Money`, `SmallMoney` or `Real`?
- For a `DateTime`, do you need `DateTime2`, `DateTimeOffset`, `DateTime`, or `SmallDateTime`?
- Are you using `Nullable` types, like `int?`? Those should most likely give the same `SqlDbType` as the underlying type.

Also, just providing a `Type` tells you nothing of other constraints, like field size and precision. Making the right decision is also about how the data is used in your application and how it is stored in the database.

The best thing to do is really to let an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) do this for you.

**Code**

```
public static class SqlHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> typeMap;

    // Create and populate the dictionary in the static constructor
    static SqlHelper()
    {
        typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();

        typeMap[typeof(string)]         = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        typeMap[typeof(char[])]         = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        typeMap[typeof(byte)]           = SqlDbType.TinyInt;
        typeMap[typeof(short)]          = SqlDbType.SmallInt;
        typeMap[typeof(int)]            = SqlDbType.Int;
        typeMap[typeof(long)]           = SqlDbType.BigInt;
        typeMap[typeof(byte[])]         = SqlDbType.Image;
        typeMap[typeof(bool)]           = SqlDbType.Bit;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime)]       = SqlDbType.DateTime2;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset)] = SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset;
        typeMap[typeof(decimal)]        = SqlDbType.Money;
        typeMap[typeof(float)]          = SqlDbType.Real;
        typeMap[typeof(double)]         = SqlDbType.Float;
        typeMap[typeof(TimeSpan)]       = SqlDbType.Time;
        /* ... and so on ... */
    }

    // Non-generic argument-based method
    public static SqlDbType GetDbType(Type giveType)
    {
        // Allow nullable types to be handled
        giveType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(giveType) ?? giveType;

        if (typeMap.ContainsKey(giveType))
        {
            return typeMap[giveType];
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"{giveType.FullName} is not a supported .NET class");
    }

    // Generic version
    public static SqlDbType GetDbType<T>()
    {
        return GetDbType(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
var sqlDbType = SqlHelper.GetDbType<string>();
// or:
var sqlDbType = SqlHelper.GetDbType(typeof(DateTime?));
// or:
var sqlDbType = SqlHelper.GetDbType(property.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Looks good! I would only add a check to see if the type exists (`ContainsKey`) in the dictionary and if not throw a `NotSupportedException` (or custom exception) with your own detailed message instead of the default `KeyNotFoundException`. This might make for easier troubleshooting later if a non supported type is ever passed in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have edited the answer to throw an `ArgumentException`, as the `NotSupportedException` is not meant for this type of thing.

Answer (score 11):

It appears that this sort of lookup table is already available, albeit not in `System.Data` (or `.Object` or `.Type`) but rather in System.Web.

Project -> Add Reference -> System.Web -> OK

Then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx also says

> When setting command parameters, the SqlDbType and DbType are linked.
>   Therefore, setting the DbType changes the SqlDbType to a supporting
>   SqlDbType.

So, this should theoretically work;)

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server; // SqlDataRecord and SqlMetaData
using System;
using System.Collections; // IEnumerator and IEnumerable
using System.Collections.Generic; // general IEnumerable and IEnumerator
using System.Data; // DataTable and SqlDataType
using System.Data.SqlClient; // SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlParameter
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; // for Parameters.Convert... functions

private static SqlDbType TypeToSqlDbType(Type t) {
    DbType dbtc = Parameters.ConvertTypeCodeToDbType(t.GetTypeCodeImpl());
    SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
    // DbParameter dp = new DbParameter();
    // dp.DbType = dbtc;
    sp.DbType = dbtc;
    return sp.SqlDbType;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect information for what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

My office mate gave me the idea to try a property of SqlParameter:

```
Func<Object, SqlDbType> getSqlType = val => new SqlParameter("Test", val).SqlDbType;
Func<Type, SqlDbType> getSqlType2 = type => new SqlParameter("Test", type.IsValueType?Activator.CreateInstance(type):null).SqlDbType;

//returns nvarchar...
Object obj = "valueToTest";
getSqlType(obj).Dump();
getSqlType2(typeof(String)).Dump();

//returns int...
obj = 4;
getSqlType(obj).Dump();
getSqlType2(typeof(Int32)).Dump();

//returns bigint...
obj = Int64.MaxValue;
getSqlType(obj).Dump();
getSqlType2(typeof(Int64)).Dump();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8heM4H

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle nullable types.

Comment: In what way?  I casted some of the literals (ie (int?)4) and it seems to work - still returns int as the sql data type.  Remember this is getting the equivalent data type in sql.  Unlike .net where you really have two types, nullability is inherint in the data type and then is denied via contraint.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I was thinking about and this works for System.Data.SqlTypes types. I'll leave it here just in case it helps someone in the future.

I do something like this:

```
object objDbValue = DbReader.GetValue(columnIndex);
Type sqlType = DbReader.GetFieldType(columnIndex);
Type clrType = null;

if (sqlType.Name.StartsWith("Sql"))
{   
    var objClrValue = objDbValue.GetType()
                                .GetProperty("Value")
                                .GetValue(objDbValue, null);
    clrType = objClrValue.GetType();
}
```

Because every SqlDbType has a .Value property which is the actual underlying CLR type I use reflection to get it. It's too bad SqlDbType doesn't have some interface that would hold this .Value property and reflection wouldn't be needed.
It's not perfect but you don't have to manually create, maintain or populate  a dictionary. You can just look up a type in an existing dict, and if it doesn't exist use the upper method to add the mapping automatically.
Pretty much auto-generated.
Also takes care of any new types that SQL Server might receive in the future.

Comment: "Edited: Not sure where the comment I was replying to went." ah, you're right, for the other direction i don't have a better answer than a pre-populated dictionary. Although usually the use case is from sql type to clr type because one sql type can map to multiple clr types.

Comment: Looks like [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enumeration so I am not sure how that holds additional information about a CLR Type. Also for creating queries it would not work, only for translating results from a query to the correct CLR type.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment right away because I wanted to rethink a little. My initial comment was *"Doesn't this go the opposite direction?"*. Now I'm more with @Igor, as the desired `SqlDbType` is an enumeration.

Comment: you're right, I was constantly thinking of System.Data.SqlTypes namespace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes(v=vs.110).aspx my bad.