# Should I use the Date or DateTime SqlDbType when adding a DateTime C# value for a Date SQL Server field?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I've got a table with a field of Date data type. Although I would expect just the raw date in that field when inserting a value into it like so:

```
update reportsgenerated
set begindate = '2016-02-01'
where rptgenid = 2;
```

...it actually sems to store a date time value, as it is represented in LINQPad as "*2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM*".

The C# value I'm assigning to the parameter when inserting is a DateTime type (as C# doesn't have a "Date"-only type):

```
DateTime begDate = // bla
```

That being the case, should I designate the parameter as a Date type, to match the table:

```
insertRptsGenerated.Parameters.Add("@BeginDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = begDate;
```

...or as a DateTime type, to match the assigned value's type:

```
insertRptsGenerated.Parameters.Add("@BeginDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = begDate;
```

?

Comment: You'd better to use DATE type if it is available in your SQL version. I guess in C# it won't be different than DATETIME fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET System Type to SqlDbType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745226/net-system-type-to-sqldbtype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET already knows what type it is in .NET. You are being asked what type to use on the other end, hence the **SqlDb** part of the `SqlDbType` ;-). You should match, as closely as possible, the type of the parameter on the database side.

For the complete list of mappings, please see the MSDN page for [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

That chart shows:

SQL Server `DATE` == .NET `DateTime` == `SqlDbType.Date`

Comment: According to the linked post, the mapping for C#'s DateTime is SqlDbType.DateTime2; I see nothing for Date.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon You are thinking about this from the wrong direction. SQL Server has more granular types due to being ultimately concerned with physical storage. What is most important is the SQL Server type. Please see the link I just added to my answer (which I noticed was also noted in the Question linked by Plutonix).