C# DateTime precision conversion issue when querying SQL Server
I have a SQL Server column ShipDateTimeUTC of datatype datetime which only supports a precision of 3 milliseconds.
We want to query this to get records greater than the lastSuccessfulPullDateTime (using Entity Framework and Linq):
DateTime comparisonDateTime = lastSuccessfulPullDateTime;

qryAllCartonsToSync = schRepos.SearchFor(o => 
    o.OrderHeader.StoreFrontId == _storeFront.Id 
    && o.ShipDateTimeUTC > comparisonDateTime
    && o.IsReturn == false
);

The problem is that C# DateTime has a precision of 7, so the query posted to SQL Server has the datetime as 2024-08-07 16:06:06.9230000.
I found out that SQL Server first converts the database values up to a precision of 7, then applies the predicate. And due to the way SQL Server rounds datetime up the result is 2024-08-07 16:06:06.9233333 which is greater than the predicate of 2024-08-07 16:06:06.9230000 and hence that record is included in the results, despite me not wanting to get that row.
Is there a way to "cast" a C# datetime down to precision of 3 or some other way to accomplish this without changing the SQL Server column type to a datatype of datetime2(7)?

I know you can cast data type from C# to SQL data types (mostly used when you need a SQL.NULL  value, but you should be able to do it for the date time as well.  using SqlDbType  to convert.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439006/1459036

This runs an ADO.Net raw SQL parameterized query behind the scenes, where the query parameter type was inferred to be DateTime(7).  ADO.Net is also perfectly happy to map .NET DateTime values to SQL DateTime values... and for many years this has been the default. Not sure what the latest EF may be doing, but you may need to set the parameter type yourself to get the favorable mapping. Oh, and the .AddMilliseconds(0) is useless and not at all helpful or needed.

Not really a good answer, but you might be able to use EF.Functions.DateTimeFromParts(...) to reconstruct and use the precise desired DATETIME value on the SQL side. Perhaps something like o.ShipDateTimeUTC > EF.Functions.DateTimeFromParts(comparisonDateTime.Year, ..., comparisonDateTime.Millisecond).  This should pass each comparisonDateTime component as a separate parameter to the query and construct the old DATETIME type using the SQL DATETIMEFROMPARTS() function.  Even if milliseconds is slightly off (666 vs 667), the value should round to the desired nearest 1/300 second.

@JoelCoehoorn thanks, this would probably work but was hoping to avoid having to re-write the query using ADO, etc. The .AddMilliseconds(0) I forgot to remove. I was actually adding 1 millisecond as my short term Hack to get the query to work at the risk of missing records between the 0.363 and 0.364ms marks.

@TN thanks, but it looks like EF.Functions.DateTimeFromParts(...) is for EF Core...I'm using EF for asp.net MVC. I also don't understand how to use this in conjunction with SQL DATETIMEFROMPARTS() in Linq to Sql to get this to ultimately work. Or are you suggesting I use raw sql or a stored procedure vs Linq to Sql?

@crichavin - I took a look at what I think is the equivalent EF6 SqlFunctions Class, but could not find a useful alternative. You might be able to define a custom user function mapping so that a LINQ expression reference to ConvertToOldDateTime(comparisonDateTime) translates to something like CONVERT(DATETIME, @comparisonDateTime) in SQL, but I do not have experience doing that. Perhaps someone else that does can help.

This looks familiar, EF6 issue 49 EF6 issue 578 perhaps there are some workarounds mentioned there one can use?

manually truncate the precision of your DateTime value to milliseconds before using it in the LINQ query. Here’s a helper method to truncate the precision:
public static DateTime TruncateToMilliseconds(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Ticks - (dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond), dateTime.Kind);
}


This won't help. They are already providing a value truncated to milliseconds. It does nothing to avoid the issues with the SQL Server datetime datatype treating this as being 3 recurring
